# What is the difference between setJSON, setData and loadData?

Tags: sapui5, jsonmodel

This is regarding the mentioned methods of `sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel` in SAPUI5:

- `setJSON`
- `setData`
- `loadData`

What is the difference between these 3 methods? When do we use these methods and can we use more than 1 of them for the same purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the well documented **[API Reference](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel/overview)** for `JSONModel`.

In summary (from SAP Documentation):

**`setData`**: Sets the data, passed as a JS object tree, to the model.

e.g

```js
var data = {
  "ProductCollection": [{
    "titleId": 0,
    "Name": "Olayinka O",
    "ProductId": "001",
    "chartValue": 75,
    "ProductPicUrl": "sap-icon://competitor"
  }]
};


var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(data);

//OR 
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(); 
oModel.setData(data); 


/*setdata, could also be a odata url in json format*/
```

**`loadData`**: 
Load JSON-encoded data from the server using a GET HTTP request and store the resulting JSON data in the model. Note: Due to browser security restrictions, most "Ajax" requests are subject to the same origin policy, the request can not successfully retrieve data from a different domain, subdomain, or protocol.

e.g. you can use this to load/GET changes to the data/model and automatically updates the view if that specific model has being binded by reloading the url. **If you use load**, you don't need the other two in my opinion and `loadData` with not work on local json data.

```js
var sURL = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://services.odata.org/V3/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Products?$format=json";
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();

//if called in setInterval, all changes in the backend will be updated in the view if binded in this case every second

setInterval(oModel.loadData(sURL, true), 1000);
```

**`setJSON`** : 
Sets the data, passed as a string in JSON format, to the model.

i.e. Same as Set Data but strict JSON

Answer (score 2):

Luckily, the source code of UI5 is quite readable and often the better documentation than most of the API descriptions. Here is what each one of the APIs does basically:

### setJSON

"Parse the JSON text and call `setData`"

> ```js
> JSONModel.prototype.setJSON = function(sJSON, bMerge) {
>     var oJSONData;
>     try {
>         oJSONData = jQuery.parseJSON(sJSON);
>         this.setData(oJSONData, bMerge);
>     } catch (e) {
>         // ...
>     }
> };
> ```
>
> <sup>[Source](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/3dcacdd1133bc0c93796baf2d79c7000710d3459/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel.js#L143-L161)</sup>

### setData

"Store the data and notify all dependent bindings (`checkUpdate`)"

> ```js
> JSONModel.prototype.setData = function(oData/*plain JS object*/, bMerge){
>     if (bMerge) {
>         this.oData = /* merge with existing data */;
>     } else {
>         this.oData = oData;
>     } // ...
>     this.checkUpdate(); // notifies dependent bindings
> };
> ```
>
> <sup>[Source](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/3dcacdd1133bc0c93796baf2d79c7000710d3459/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel.js#L75-L94)</sup>

### loadData

"Load data from the given remote URL and call `setData`" --> Please check the [source here](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/3dcacdd1133bc0c93796baf2d79c7000710d3459/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel.js#L174-L269).

---

## In short, they all call `setData` at some point.

Which API to call in which situation depends on in which format you have the data available.

- The data are in JSON text --> `setJSON`
- The data are somewhere else --> `loadData`
- I already have the data in JS object / array ---> `setData`

Comment: I face the issue using `setData()`, I try to provide an array with a proper single JS-object inside and when I call it, the application hangs. At the same time, `loadData()` works perfectly. I can't guess what's the reason of the issue.

Comment: @MikeB. Interesting. Could you create an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with e.g. JSBin or Plunker? I could take a look. Maybe it's a bug

Comment: thanx for your proposal, I'll try. It's important to note, that I'm using an outdated version of UI5 — 1.44.40, which night have some issues with `setData()`.

Answer (score 1):

**setData**

> You have a JavaScript object and want to use this data as your model

```
const oJSONData = {
    data: {
        id: 4,
        first_name: "Eve",
        last_name: "Holt",
        avatar: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/marcoramires/128.jpg"
    }
};
oJSONModel.setData(oData);
```

---

**setJSON**

> You have a String that when parsed represents a JavaScript object and want to use this data as your model

```
const sJSONData = '{"data":{"id":4,"first_name":"Eve","last_name":"Holt","avatar":"https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/marcoramires/128.jpg"}}';
oJSONModel.setJSON(sJSONData);
```

---

**loadData**

> You want to access a remote API which returns data as JSON and want to use this data as your model

```
const sURL = "https://reqres.in/api/users/4";
oJSONModel.loadData(sURL);
```